# Can't access a Console hosted WCF service from a remote client on LAN

Tags: c#, wcf, networking, .net-4.5

For some days now, i'm trying to access my WCF Service from another computer on my LAN and just can't access it.

Locally it works fine though.

Majority of the similar questions i could find are using IIS to host the service.

I tried to shut down the firewall but i couldn't get any effect.

Here are the config files, please ask if you need more :

Client's App.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <client>
            <endpoint name="default"
                      address="http://myhostIP:3100/"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      contract="ServiceInterface.IService"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Here is the Host App.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="ServiceTest.Service">
                <endpoint address="http://0.0.0.0:3100"
                          contract="ServiceInterface.IService"
                          binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

If you guys got any ideas...
I couldn't find any informations

**EDIT :**

I'm using a console application to host the service

Telnet connection from local and remote hosts are working

**EDIT 2 :**

I just seen that i made a mistake copying the App.config file. The binding type should be `wsDualHttpBinding` instead of `basicHttpBinding`

I also could get an error message :

First one is that the "Caller couldn't identicate itself to the WCF service"

I tried then to set the security to none (for troubleshooting purposes) and i only got a timeout exception

**EDIT 3 :**

In a console app :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceTest.Service));
   host.Open();
   Console.WriteLine("Server Started");
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Edit 4:**

The complete solution is available here https://github.com/sidewinder94/smallChatSolution

Comment: maybe it is because firewall is blocking port 3100.

Comment: are you hosting your WCF service on IIS ?

Comment: @daryal Firewall shut down, it's in the question ;)

Comment: @Ksven no, i'm hosting the service using a console application

Comment: telnet from the client to the host on port 3100 to see if it is really reachable :)

Comment: @DimiToulakis Telnet connection is working, just tested

Comment: How about changing the IP on the host config to the real IP?

Comment: @DimiToulakis I've also trid that... didn't worked, i also tried to replace the IP adress wit the Computer name, didn't work either

Comment: @Sidewinder94 try to run wcfTestClient.exe from the client machine. It will try to connect and can generate config for you (when connected)

Comment: hmm, how are you creating your host? can you post the code?

Comment: @oleksa Ok, i tried, i had to add a mex endpoint but the test tool suceeded to connect. Copied the configuration into the client but the client still can't connect

Comment: alright, have your solution working now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution for your issue.

**Client's app config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <client>
            <endpoint name="default" 
                      contract="ChatDllContracts.IService" 
                      binding="netTcpBinding" 
                      address="net.tcp://myHostIp:3100/"
                      bindingConfiguration="mynet"/>
        </client>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="mynet" sendTimeout="00:00:05" portSharingEnabled="true">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**ChatServer's app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="ChatDll.Service">
                <endpoint contract="ChatDllContracts.IService"
                          binding="netTcpBinding"
                          address="net.tcp://localhost:3100"
                          bindingConfiguration="mynet"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="mynet" sendTimeout="00:00:05" portSharingEnabled="true">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Please keep in mind that you need to enable the **Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service** (on the server & client side) in order to get it working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll try that, any idea why the `wsDualHttpBinding` is not working ?
Do i really need to set the securoty mode to none ? Or was it placed here only for debugging purposes ?

Comment: I would suggest to go through the example for wsHttpBinding to get the basics about it (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648431.aspx). I have set the security mode to "None" for easiness. You can read further on it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731316(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There's no need to enable the Net.tcp port sharing on the client, i just tested with two remote clients, and one local. All worked correctly, i only enabled the Net.Tcp port sharing on the server though.
Thank's for the help anyway.

Comment: thx for the info... I had another application running on that port on my side... yw

Comment: I can confirm this, i tried to launch a second instance on one of the remote clients and it crashed the instant i tried to connect.